# Translating and understanding the @Scheduled cron message

Tags: spring, methods, cron, scheduled-tasks, implementation

I have this code.

This `cron` message means "do this method every Sunday in 01.00 a.m." or I make a mistake translating this?

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 1 0 * * ?")
private void notificationsScheduler() {
    //implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression

```
"0 1 0 * * ?"
```

means: At 00:01:00am every day

As per your requirement : At 01:00:00am, on every Sunday, every month

Use:

```
0 0 1 ? * SUN *
```

Follow this https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

you are wrong, it means every day.

Comment: like: 2019-12-24 00:01:00
2019-12-25 00:01:00
2019-12-26 00:01:00
2019-12-27 00:01:00
2019-12-28 00:01:00
2019-12-29 00:01:00